# pointers and local variables in C

Tags: c, variables, pointers, local, avr

Hoping to have not created a duplicated topic here are my doubts:

I'm working on an Atmel Xmega processor, i'm using AtmelStudio (gcc) and i have to send an area of memory through a device in situation similar to this:

```
volatile unsigned char *areatobetransferred;

    void afunction (unsigned int someint)
    {
       unsigned int otherint;
       otherint=(someint<<8) | (someint>>8); //used to swap lobyte and hibyte
       otherfunction ((volatile unsigned char *)&otherint);
    }

    void otherfunction (volatile unsigned char * pointedarea)
    {
         areatobetransferred=pointedarea;
         bytestosend=2;
         StartSenderInterrupt(); 
    }

    ISR (SenderInterrupt)
    {
       deviceport=*areatobetransferred;
       if (length<bytestosend) 
         {areatobetransferred++;
          bytestosend++;}
       else StopSenderInterrupt();
    }
```

Now, my problem is that although when i call this routine  from another module i get the correct behaviour, in another module i cannot get the correct result.
In specific, in the ISR, instead of having the correct value of the local variable "otherint" i'm passing as a pointer, i get just garbage, unless i declare the local variable as static.
The pointer value is absolutely correct if i read it into the calling routine and into the interrupt service routine, while the pointed value is correct into the calling routine "afunction" only.
Looking more in deep, i see that if declare the local variable as non-static it is allocated on the stack, on the far end of the ram (as it should be) while, if declared static, it is placed at the beginning of the ram space.

Having no debugging tool and poor knowledge of assembler, i'm supposing this:
-when i declare a local variable its value is preserved while and only if i'm into its scope
-if i call other routines, or in case of an interrupt (as in my case), i have the pointer to my local variable storing the correct position where my variable was but maybe what is now at that address is eventually overwritten with other data, so that's why i'm getting just garbage.
-if i declare the variable as static, it is allocated once and its value and position is never changed through ISR or when calling other routines, so i always read the correct values.

Finally i think that is only a matter of luck that it works as desired on the other module: if i grow my project or i change "that" particular thing, i think it 'll begin to fail also there.

Is it my guessing correct?

Thanks

Comment: You can just cast to unsigned char*, no need to add volatile into the cast there.

Comment: Right, all your stack variables are destroyed when they go out of scope, the space being reused for unrelated other stack info at any time. Any pointers pointing there thus point to completely unrelated data structures.

Comment: I don't know this CPU. Can you continue your function after issuing interrupt? If not, then stack is surely be broken and there is no way to hold data here. If yes, than stack should be held. Also, why do you incrementing pointer in interrupt handler? It will point to somewhere invalid.

Comment: Yes, all other is running fine, just what is related to those routines i told about is messed up. I do increment the pointer into the interrupt and it points to garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Your ISR is attempting to access `areatobetransferred` and this is (indirectly) set outside the ISR to `&otherint`. However, `otherint` is on the stack of `afunction`. Therefore, if `afunction` exits before the ISR is called, the value of `otherint` will become undefined. That's why making it static works. As an alternative, `malloc()` it and `free()` it when the ISR is done.